# How to show YouTube video in webView on Android

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube, android-videoview

I want show **YouTube videos** in my application and for this I want use `WebView`.
For use `WebView` and show videos I write below codes :

```
            WebSettings settings = content_newsWebView.getSettings();
            content_newsWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            content_newsWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            content_newsWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            content_newsWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/cache");
            content_newsWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            content_newsWebView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/databases");
            settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
            content_newsWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
            content_newsWebView.loadData(response.body().getData().getDescription(), "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

When run application, show me video but not **responsive**!
Show me video biggest! Please see this image to understand my mean : [Image Link](https://s15.postimg.org/3xi9mwnhn/image.png)

I want show **responsive Youtube** video in my application.

I get video link from server with this **Json** :

```
> "<p><iframe frameborder=\"0\"
> src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/NcoBDgJ3ZBw\"
> style=\"width:100%;min-height: 400px;\"></iframe></p>\n\n<p>The Harry
> Potter star plays an Israeli backpacker in the upcoming thriller from
> <a
> href=\"http://example.com/Celebrities/276442/greg_mclean\"><strong>Greg McLean</strong></a> (<a
> href=\"http://example.com/Movies/94393/the_belko_experiment\"><strong>The
> Belko Experiment</strong></a>, <a
> href=\"http://example.com/Movies/1397/wolf_creek\"><strong>Wolf
> Creek</strong></a>).</p>\n\n<p><a
> href=\"http://example.com/Celebrities/10139/daniel_radcliffe\"><strong>Radcliffe</strong></a>,
> 27, is a young adventurer going on a dream trip into the Amazonian
> rain forest along with two friends and a mysterious guide named
> Karl.</p>\n\n<p>Abandoned by their guide among the dangerous jungle
> creatures, Yossi (<a
> href=\"http://example.com/Celebrities/10139/daniel_radcliffe\"><strong>Radcliffe</strong></a>)
> and his friends are left with little means to survive, ending up in
> psychological battles with themselves.</p>\n\n<p>Starring <a
> href=\"http://example.com/Celebrities/64592/alex_russell\"><strong>Alex Russell</strong></a>, <a
> href=\"http://example.com/Celebrities/53829/thomas_kretschmann\"><strong>Thomas
> Kretschmann</strong></a> and <strong>Yasmin Kassim</strong>, Jungle
> premiers at Melbourne International Film Festival on Aug. 3.</p>\n"
```

How can I show **responsive youtube** video in my application?

Please help me guys, **I really need your Helps.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play Youtube HTML5 embedded Video in Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323169/play-youtube-html5-embedded-video-in-android-webview)

Comment: @KaranSharma, I try this but not work me

Comment: the json you have provided is wrong format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code: Change the URL of video in the string.

```
String frameVideo = "<html><body>Video From YouTube<br><iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/47yJ2XCRLZs\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

    WebView displayYoutubeVideo = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mWebView);
    displayYoutubeVideo . setWebViewClient ( New  WebViewClient () {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    WebSettings webSettings = displayYoutubeVideo . getSettings ();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    displayYoutubeVideo.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: thanks my friend, can you edit your codes with my above codes? please I am amateur. please

Comment: you can use this code independently and you can make changes on top of it based on your requirements