# Embeded Video in html content does not play on WebView

Tags: java, android, html, android-webview

I am working on app which contain inline image and embeded video in HTML content. video displayed but clicking on play button video wont play. I have used following code of loading html content on webview.

```
WebSettings mainViewsettings = witContentWebView.getSettings();
mainViewsettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mainViewsettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
mainViewsettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);

mainViewsettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mainViewsettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mainViewsettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

witContentWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() 
{

});

witContentWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", witsContentStr,"text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

I have also set android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in manifest file, but I did not get any success. Could you guys help me  solveout in this.

Comment: is it from youtube ? try setPluginState(PluginState.ON)

Comment: yes. it from youtube. I have also use this, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem in is codec? Just open a browser? You use Chromium Web View or old Web View? (Android version)

Answer (score 0):

Answer shamelessly copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3520920/1602333.

I am not sure if this is what you need. Anyway I hope the following be useful.
You can use the iframe method that youtube provides to play its videos. If the browser supports html5 will show the video with it, otherwise with flash.

You can use the following code as an example  <`iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bIPcobKMB94" frameborder="0">`

in the above example the video id is bIPcobKMB94. You can change this id and show your video.

You can access a live example of it [here](http://jsbin.com/ijixe4/3)

[More infromation for youtube iframe](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html)

[YouTube HTML5 Video Player](http://www.youtube.com/html5)

Comment: Its only play audio. video is not visible.

Comment: which android version?

Comment: I have checked this in JellyBean 4.1.2, Kitkat 4.4 and lollipop 5.0

Comment: <html><head></head><body><div>
<p style="font-size:12pt;">hrgrtuhjkhfj</p>

<div class="embededContent oembed-provider- oembed-provider-youtube" data-align="none" data-oembed="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lzQ8hnUMxnA" data-resizetype="noresize"><iframe allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" frameborder="0" height="349" scrolling="no" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/lzQ8hnUMxnA?wmode=transparent&amp;jqoemcache=JHCko" width="425"></iframe></div>

</div>
</body></html>

Comment: Above I have posted HTML content what i am getting from server to show on Webview.

Comment: surprisingly , in my 4.1 and 5.0 device , it's working. I have taken iframe directly in body tag without any div.

Comment: I have checked this by just remove the div tag it also does not work for me.

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<!-- <h1>Hello World!</h1>
<p><a href="two.html">Local link</a></p>-->
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/lzQ8hnUMxnA" frameborder="0">

</body>
</html>

Comment: try my code , it works for me in 5.0 and even my younger brother also likes chhota bheem very much :D

Comment: It also did not work on any of android version device I have. rather it play on default browser of phone.